# Properly creating object instances for unit test

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I'm trying to run a unit test in a separate unit test file located in the same directory, but running the unit test file just runs the functionality within the main file, while not calling upon the instance I've tried to create. Here's the code for the main file:

```
class ListOperations:
    def list_copy(l):
        return [x for x in l]

    print(list_copy(["What","A", "List"]))
```

Here's the unit test code located in the same directory:

```
import unittest
from basicfunction import ListOperations

class TestListOperations(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_1(self):
        ListOperations = ListOperations()
        self.assertEqual(ListOperations.list_copy(["This", "Is", "Just", "A", "List"]), ["This", "Is", "Just", "A", "List"])

    def test_2(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I try to run the unit test, I get the output:

```
E.
======================================================================
ERROR: test_1 (__main__.TestListOperations)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/path/basicfunction.ut.py", line 8, in test_1
    ListOperations = ListOperations()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ListOperations' referenced before assignment

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
['What', 'A', 'List']
```

How could I set this test up properly?

Edit:
`@staticmethod` helped to run the test above, but I'm having issues with methods with two parameters. If I try to create an instance outside of the unittest class:

```
lop = ListOperations()
intersect1 = ["Pikachu", "Evolves", "Into", "Raichu"]
intersect2 = ["Raichu", "Does", "Not", "Evolve", "Into", "Anything"]
print(lop.list_intersect(intersect1, intersect2))
```

Output is `['Into', 'Raichu']` in the main file, but I get an error of `TypeError: list_intersect() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given` when I try to import into the test file. Any thoughts on how I could resolve this error?

Comment: Do you know what a bound method is? A static one? Try with `@staticmethod def list_copy(l):`

Comment: @Pynchia Modifying the variable name of the instance combined with `@staticmethod` did the trick! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in OOP for Python, when you define a method you will need to put the parameter `self` in the first position. This is to give the method access to the underlying object that it is tied to.

```py
class ListOperations:
    def list_copy(self, l):
        return [x for x in l]
```

The other issue causing the error message is your variable name `ListOperations`. That word is taken by your class `ListOpertions` so you can change it to `listOperations` so that they don't collide.

```py
import unittest
from basicfunction import ListOperations

class TestListOperations(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_1(self):
        listOperations = ListOperations()
        self.assertEqual(listOperations.list_copy(["This", "Is", "Just", "A", "List"]), ["This", "Is", "Just", "A", "List"])

    def test_2(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: These functions are only intended to take one or two arguments though, i.e. the lists. I do have other constructors within other classes than use `self`, but not this one. In any case, I get an error of `TypeError: list_copy() missing 1 required positional argument: 'l'`

Comment: so to use `list_copy` you will need to do `listOperations.list_copy(['any', 'list'])`. You might be misunderstanding how `self` works in python? All methods (that aren't static or class methods) in python need `self` as the first parameter to access the instance of the class. https://www.programiz.com/article/python-self-why

Answer (score 0):

I think there is small bug in your code
you are using **same name** for variable as the name of your class `ListOperations`.

Try changing variable name to something else and run the code

For example

```
lop = ListOperations() 
self.assertEqual(lop.list_copy(["This", "Is", "Just", "A", "List"]), ["This", "Is", "Just", "A", "List"])
```

Comment: I had thought that was causing the issue before posting the question, but I get an error of `TypeError: list_copy() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` when doing that. I also get the print out from the main file

Comment: I think you got that `TypeError` becuase you might have forgot to properly close the closing bracket `)`.....Try copy paste my line of code and see if it works and let me know if you still face some issue